# Addresses of identical function template instantiations across compilation units

Tags: c++, function, templates, linker, c++-address

Why does this work?

I see similar SO questions stating that it does, but could someone explain it in more detail?  Particularly, is this behavior protected by a standard?

**i.h**

```
#ifndef I_H_
#define I_H_

typedef void (*FuncPtr)();

template<typename T>
void FuncTemplate() {}

class C {};

#endif
```

**a.cc**

```
#include "i.h"

FuncPtr a() {
  return &FuncTemplate<C>;
}
```

**b.cc**

```
#include "i.h"

FuncPtr b() {
  return &FuncTemplate<C>;
}
```

**m.cc**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "i.h"

FuncPtr a();
FuncPtr b();

int main() {
  std::cout << (a() == b() ? "equal" : "not equal") << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Then

```
$ g++ -c -o a.o a.cc
$ g++ -c -o b.o b.cc
$ g++ -c -o m.o m.cc
$ g++ a.o b.o m.o -o prog
$ ./prog
equal
```

Tossing `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -ansi` onto all the `g++` calls produces the same.

My (naive) understanding is that `FuncTemplate` is instantiated once in each of the `a.o` and `b.o` compilation units, and so the addresses should each point to one copy.  How do these end up the same after all, and is this behavior portable or protected?

**EDIT** The shared library case:

```
$ g++ -shared -o liba.so a.cc
$ g++ -shared -o libb.so b.cc
$ g++ -c -o m.o m.cc
$ g++ -L. -la -lb m.o -o prog
$ ./prog
equal
```

Comment: I would add to your question "what's happening when you replace object files by shared libraries ?".

Comment: Have you tried this with anything in the template function or class bodies?  I wouldn't think it would make a difference, but this is certainly an interesting result.  I'm also curious as to what would happen if you moved the empty class `C` into `a.cc` and `b.cc`.  I assume it would change the result.

Comment: @keith.layne Yea, adding trivial (but template parameter dependent) code to the `FuncTemplate`, or various members to `C` doesn't change anything.  As for moving `C`, the `#include` effectively does that already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is covered under the one definition rule:

### 3.2   One definition rule [basic.def.odr]

#### Paragraph 5:

> There can be more than one definition of a class type (Clause 9), enumeration type (7.2), inline function with external linkage (7.1.2), class template (Clause 14), **non-static function template (14.5.6)**, static data member of a class template (14.5.1.3), member function of a class template (14.5.1.1), or template specialization for which some template parameters are not specified (14.7, 14.5.5) in a program provided that each definition appears in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements. Given such an entity named D defined in more than one translation unit, then

There is a whole list of criteria that follow that have to be-adhered to or its undefined behavior. In the above these do hold. Then ...

> If the definitions of D satisfy all these requirements, then the program shall behave as if there were a single definition of D.

So technically you can have a copy of the function in each translation unit.

It looks like the wording in the last phrase though makes it a requirement that they all behave the same. This means taking the address of any of these objects should result in the same address.

Comment: It later specifies that the program behaves as if there is one defintion of D. I believe that extends to taking a function's address. :)

Comment: @MSN. I was just reading that. I have to agree with you for now. While I check that out.

Answer (score 4):

This is guaranteed by the standard as it does not violate the one definition rule. In essence, if the declaration and definition of an inline function or template function is the same in multiple translation units, the program shall behave as though there is one definition of it, which extends to its address, when taken. [See my answer to another question that involved static members of template classes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562096/compile-time-constant-id/7562583#7562583)

As for the relevant section of the standard `[basic.def.odr]`:

> ... If the definitions of D satisfy all these requirements, then the
>   program shall behave as if there were a single definition of D. If the
>   definitions of D do not satisfy these requirements, then the behavior
>   is undefined.