# What is C++11's equivalent of Java's instanceof

Tags: java, c++, c++11, instanceof, multiple-languages

I want to know what the modern C++11 equivalent of Java's instanceof. I have seen this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500493/c-equivalent-of-instanceof) but it is quite old and was wondering if there's a more modern, better solution in C++11?

I was hoping there's a possibility of using a switch construct without having to resort to a manual enum class.

```
class A {

};

class B : public A {

}

class C : public A {

}

on_event(A& obj)
{
    switch (obj) {
       case A:
       case B:
       case C:
    }
}
```

My base class does not have any virtual methods or functions. I am representing an expression tree for a parser and the base class is just a polymorphic holder - like an ADT in Haskell/OCaml.

Comment: Are you asking for `dynamic_cast<>`? That's not c++11 specific.

Comment: Nothing changed: there's no reflection in standard C++. If you want to switch on runtime type information, you `dynamic_cast`

Comment: Maybe of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25495733/596781

Comment: -1 The question is now absurd: You're asking for an "equivalent to Java" of something that is completely unrelated to and uncomparable with Java.

Comment: Also, it seems insane to want to manually reinvent something which is precisely solved by runtime polymorphism in the language.

Comment: I don't see how it is "absurd" and you come across as rude to me. I want to know the best way to implement my on_event function to handle the different sub-classes that doesn't have virtual methods/members in the base class (A). I know how I would do it in Java but wanting to know the best way in C++.

Comment: _"My base class does not have any virtual methods or functions"_ and _"the base class is just a polymorphic holder"_ appear to be contradicting statements. Since `A` is a _base class_ it **should have a virtual destructor**. This sounds like an XY problem anyway, chances are you can avoid the `switch` statement altogether by using virtual functions.

Comment: Despite it having been downvoted, I want to draw your attention to @Kastaneda 's answer, which is definitely useful - even if not for the case of accessing subclasses through a pointer or a reference.

Answer (score 13):

The same answer still applies, and has always been like this in C++:

```
if (C * p = dynamic_cast<C *>(&obj))
{
    // The type of obj is or is derived from C
}
else
{
    // obj is not a C
}
```

This construction requires `A` to be polymorphic, i.e. to have virtual member functions.

Also note that this behaviour is different from comparing `typeid(obj) == typeid(C)`, since the latter tests for exact type identity, whereas the dynamic cast, as well as Java's `instanceof`, only test for the target type to be a base class of the type of the most-derived object.

Comment: it also requires `RTTI`, which is kinda of a pain for some C++ users .

Comment: @user2485710: I don't think that statement makes sense in the context of the *language* C++. The code is valid C++, without qualification.

Comment: if you don't have `RTTI` that thing will not work, doesn't matter what you are considering, it's just required in order to let that piece of code work properly .

Comment: @user2485710: On some IDEs (for example, Visual Studio), you need to enable the RTTI option in the project settings, but that indeed has nothing to do with the C++ language standard.

Comment: @user2485710: There's no such thing in C++. You cannot "not have RTTI" and still have C++.

Comment: What if A doesn't have any members of functions; will this still work then?

Comment: @user8090: No, it needs to have at least one virtual member function. (Typically a virtual destructor would furnish a canonical virtual member function.) [[One could possibly make an argument that if you have a program that legitimately doesn't require virtual destructors, then it doesn't require run-time polymorphism at all, possibly after some heavy refactoring.]]

Comment: @user8090: Must have at least one virtual member function (otherwise, the class will not have a V-Table, and the `dynamic_cast` operator will not be able to make the type-comparison).

Comment: @KerrekSB `You cannot "not have RTTI" and still have C++` that's a good approach to life in general, too good to be true .

Comment: I'll edit my question as my base class doesn't have any  virtual members or functions.

Comment: @user8090: Don't do that. It would make the question absurd. You're asking for a Java equivalent, but *everything* in Java is polymorphic. Ask a new question if you need to solve something C++ specific.

Comment: Since this question is tagged C++11, you could replace `C *` with `auto` ;)

Comment: @FredOverflow: It's poor hygiene to hide pointers in type aliases, so at best you should say `auto *`. I'm aware of that, but I figured `C *` is  a bit shorter and cleaner in this case.

Comment: @KerrekSB Heh you should tell Microsoft that. Literally every pointer in the win32 api is hidden in a type alias.

Comment: Shouldnt the if statement be if (C * p == dynamic_cast<C *>(&obj)) with two ='s?

Comment: @LegionDaeth: No, that wouldn't be valid syntax, nor would it be meaningful. What is `p`?

Comment: @KerrekSB Nevermind, misunderstood what was going on, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ plain old data (POD) has no runtime type information.  The classes described all take exactly 1 byte, and have identical runtime representations in any compiler with the empty base class optimization.

As such what you want cannot be done.

Adding a virtual destructor to the base class adds in RTTI, and `dynamic_cast` support.

Adding an `enum` or `int` field to the base that gets initialized differently for each derived class also works.

Yet another option is to create a template function, and store a pointer to it, like so:

```
using my_type_id=void(*)();
template<class>void get_my_type_id_helper(){};
template<class T> my_type_id get_my_type_id(){return get_my_type_id_helper<T>;}
```

and then storing a `my_type_id` in `A` initialized appropriately.  This is reinventing RTTI, and as you want more features you will approach C++ RTTI overhead.

In C++ you only pay for what you ask for: you can ask for classes without RTTI, which you did, and get it.

RTTI is Run Time Type Information.  POD is plain old data, a C++03 term.  Many classes are not POD: the easy way is to add a `virtual` destructor.  C++11 has more fine grained standard layout and aggregate terms.

Technically RTTI and POD are not opposites of each other: there are classes with no RTTI that are not POD.

Note that MSVC has options to not generate RTTI and its aggressive Comdat folding can break the manual RTTI I did above, in both cases in violation of the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are interested in the answer I've posted inside your mentioned old SO post.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49296405/1266588

The answer presents an implementation of `instanceof` without the usage of `dynamic_cast` based on C++11, *template metaprogramming* and *RTTI*. A small performance measurement application demonstrates that it is more efficient than `dynamic_cast` if you use compiler optimization.

Answer (score -1):

If you're willing to limit yourself to types known at compile-time (rather than working through pointers on instances of classes with vtables) - then C++11 and later does have an `instanceof` equivalent: It is [std::is_base_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_base_of/).

You might also want to check out [std::is_convertible](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_convertible/) and [std::is_same](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_same/).

Comment: I'm not sure how that helps him unless he makes it a function template and knows the types at compile-time. I think it's pretty clear that he's talking about runtime polymorphism

Comment: @PeterT: Completely disagree. That is, in C++, especially Modern C++, we do a whole lot with compile-time-known types, so this is a perfectly valid answer (even if it should be edited).

Answer (score -1):

Don't do that. In most cases you should review your design when you ask for `instanceof` or `dynamic_cast`.

Why? You are most likely violating [Liskov's substitiontin principle](https://alfps.wordpress.com/2012/03/11/liskovs-substitution-principle-in-c/).

How about this approach:

```
class A {
   public:
     virtual void action();
     virtual ~A();
};

class B : public A {
   public: void action() override;
};

class C : public A {
   public: void action() override;
};

void on_event(A& obj)
{
   obj.action();
}
```

Note that as @Yakk pointed out you need at least one `virtual` method anyway to get dynamic polymorphism. And there is a rule that says: When you have at least one virtual method, always also write a virtual destructor in the base class.

You can do all this with templates and specialization or type tagging but I take from your question -- coming from Java -- you don't want to go there yet. You really *like* virtual methods, don't you? Sorry, that you have to mark them in C++.

Comment: I don't think that a program that consists of 3 classes (A, B, C) violates LSP and may be considered as a good design. I wanted to downvote cause LSP part is misleading (the question is about direct alternative to instanceof for C++11 and your warnings was already mentioned in the link), but someone may finds it useful.