# C++ Functor template for class member functions

Tags: c++, c++11, embedded, functor

There is a small functor class I wrote which should be able to call class member functions by hiding a static wrapper function and a void pointer to the object. The example below does not compile due to an error when setting the wrapper function. What I want is a class member pointer as template argument. Does anyone know what is wrong there?

I think there could be another problem in the static function when calling the member function. I do not exactly know how to do this with template syntax. The minimal example compiles with C++11 enabled gcc.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class TReturn, class... TParameter>
struct Functor {

    TReturn (*ptr)(void*, TParameter...);
    void     *object;

    template<class TObject, class TMemberFunction>
    static TReturn memberCaller(void *obj, TParameter... params) {
        TObject *c = static_cast<TObject*>(obj);
        return (c->*(TObject::TMemberFunction))(params...);
    }

    TReturn operator()(TParameter... params) {
        return ptr(object, params...);
    }
};

class Test {
public:
    void func(int a) {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    Functor<void, int> f;
    Test               t;

    f.object = &t;
    f.ptr    = &Functor<void, int>::memberCaller<Test, Test::func>;

    f(100);
}
```

Comment: You need to pass a pointer to member function of `Test` class that you want to call into `Functor`. `TMemberFunction` is not a type name. Actually you can just look up how `std::function` or `fastdelegate` is implemented.

Comment: I forgot to mention that in this case there is no stl available because I use it in an embedded system.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298408/5-years-later-is-there-something-better-than-the-fastest-possible-c-delegate

Comment: What does this have to do with embedded systems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will something like this work for you?

```
#include <iostream>

template<class TObject, class T, class... TParameter>
struct Functor {

    using TMemberFunction = T (TObject::*)(TParameter...);
    TMemberFunction ptr;
    TObject     *object;


    T operator()(TParameter... params) {
        return (object->*ptr)(params...);
    }
};

class Test {
public:
    void func(int a) {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class TD;

int main() 
{
    Functor<Test, void , int> f;
    Test               t;

    f.object = &t;
    f.ptr = &Test::func;

    f(100);
}
```

Comment: Dont write your answer like a question. And maybe add some explanations instead of just dumping code.

Comment: That works fine but then I can use the Functor for only one specific class. There may be situations where not the class type counts but the function prototype.

Comment: Member functions of different classes have different types. So I'm not really see how it could be that "class type not counts"

Answer (score 2):

Set aside a few other errors, your code doesn't work for `TMemberFunction` in:

```
template<class TObject, class TMemberFunction>
static TReturn memberCaller(void *obj, TParameter... params) {
    // ...
}
```

Cannot be used to catch a pointer to a member function. `TMemberFunction` must be a type and you are not using it like that.

You can define your class as it follows instead:

```
template<class>
struct Functor;

template<class TReturn, class... TParameter>
struct Functor<TReturn(TParameter...)> {
    TReturn (*ptr)(void*, TParameter...);
    void     *object;

    template<class TObject, TReturn(TObject::*TMemberFunction)(TParameter...)>
    static TReturn memberCaller(void *obj, TParameter... params) {
        TObject *c = static_cast<TObject*>(obj);
        return (c->*TMemberFunction)(params...);
    }

    TReturn operator()(TParameter... params) {
        return ptr(object, params...);
    }
};
```

And use it this way:

```
Functor<void(int)> f;
Test               t;

f.object = &t;
f.ptr    = &Functor<void(int)>::memberCaller<Test, &Test::func>;

f(100);
```

That is, you can use now the member function as a template parameter for `memberCaller` and let it erase the type and use it internally once called.

I also slightly changed the definition of `Functor` so as to use it as:

```
Functor<void(int)>
```

That is a bit more explicit than the following when you plan to use it with a function type:

```
Functor<void, int>
```

My two cents, at least.

---

See the example above up and running on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Gi06tyWegNP1eFxk).